# How can I force illegal characters in a file name?

Tags: c#, vba, outlook

I'm trying to find a way to force illegal characters into a filename. Specifically ':' and '/'

We receive regular automated updates by email. These emails always contain illegal characters in the subject. We currently manually save off these emails for processing as a text file with the subject as the file name. This process works but is tedious.

I wrote a VBA script for saving the files and am working on a small C# application that processes these files locally before sending them of to our server.

The Outlook script simply replaces the illegal characters with a tag before saving:

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "/", "{FS}")
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, ":", "{CO}")
```

I need to either find a method to save the files as-is from in the VBA script or change the tags back to the illegal characters when I'm processing locally.

The majority of the team is running Windows 7 x64, using Outlook 2008/10.

Comment: You're looking for a way to save files with names containing '/' on Windows?

Comment: You cannot save files with illegal filenames. (If you could, the filenames wouldn't be illegal in the first place, would they?)

Comment: What do you mean by "processes these files locally before sending them of to our server"? Are the files being saved to the server, or are the contents being processed in some way and eg written to a database?

Comment: Ken: I can manually save a file with a colon and forward slash without a problem in windows which I find idiotic but have no way around this without breaking out process.

Comment: David: Basically as we get these updates I (or a team member) have to save off the emails to a folder, enumerate over each message and generate a list. We then zip up this folder and take it over a server that sits outside of our internal network and process each request.

Comment: @Daskidd When you say you can manually save file containing `/` or `:`, you are missing out an important fact: the `/` and `:` get stripped from the name. So do the same when saving your files.

Comment: @Daskidd: Are you saying you can set the name of a file to include a forward slash?  When I try to do this, I get an error that the slash is illegal.

Comment: You may want to specify which file systems you are using, as different systems have different sets of restricted characters.

Comment: @ David & Paul: The characters are not (visibly) stripped from the name nor is there a complaint. In outlook 2010, I am able to do a file->saveAs and the file retains the illegal characters in the name. I was perplexed by this too but it worked so didn't argue with it, until I started trying to automate.

Comment: @Daskidd: No, you can't. Try it from Notepad or any other software. Those are special characters and are not allowed in filenames on Windows or DOS operating systems.

Comment: It think it is a bad idea to use the subject for the filename. What happens if you get a email with a subject longer than 255 characters?

Comment: @sgmoore I didn't develop our process, I'm just trying to improve on it.

Comment: @Daskidd, In my version of Outlook 2010, File -> Save As strips out illegal characters and replaces them with spaces.

Comment: @Daskidd, Do you happen to have a plugin which replaces them with similar looking Unicode characters - such as [Modifier letter raised Colon](http://unicode-table.com/en/02F8/)?

Comment: @Josh & Ken: You're right I tried on a different system. I'll have to check if we a plugin that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution seems to be simply don't. I'm going to rework how we handle these messages rather than try to force this behavior.